# Regex - How to discard match

Tags: java, regex

How can I get a regular expression to discard a part of the match?

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=b)([xyz])(?:a*?)c");
        String string = "abyaacbxaaac";
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        while(matcher.find()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

The output here is:

```
yaac   
xaaac
```

I'd like it to output only `y` and `x` when I run `System.out.println(matcher.group());`
I.e. Discarding what is matched by`(?:a*?)`

P.S.

I know I can use `matcher.group(1)` to get `x` and `y` on its own but I'd like the entire match to output `x` and `y` only without having to access specific groups.

Comment: "Discard" in your understanding means "match discontinuous parts of text within one match operation". It is not possible, that is when you can rely on lookarounds. Or capturing groups and further post-processing. Or using a replacing approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use lookarounds in your regex to get only the part you need in match:

```
(?<=b)[xyz](?=a*c)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CVFhSy/2)

`(?=a*c)` is a positive lookahead to assert that we have `0` or more `a` followed by a `c` ahead. This is a zero width assertion so your match will still be one of `[xyz]` characters.

Comment: u're so fast. hahaha +1. I was writing ^_^

Comment: I guess this does give me the `x` and `y` but its not really what I'm looking for. I specifically would like to know if there is a way for me to discard a part of a match.

Comment: Hope you understand discard is almost opposite of a match. In Java using lookaheads is the standard way to do an assertion without matching. Even `\K` of PCRE lets you rest previously matched text only not the text that is ahead.